# How to pass params to the parent and child state at the same time in $state.go function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect a user to the particular state. I have 2 states.

First is `app` and the URL for it is `/{lang}`, so eg. `mydomain.com/en`.

The child state of `app` is `app.login`. The URL for this state is `/login/{slug}`. So full link, including `app` state, may be `mydomain.com/en/login/settings`.

Next state calls `login`, and the URL is `/login/settings` eg. `mydomain.com/login/settings`. When user enters this link, I want to redirect him to the `app.login` state and pass `settings` param for `{slug}`. But also I have to pass earlier `{lang}` param for the `app` state.

How can I pass two paramaters separetly for the `app` and `app.login` in order to redirect user.

It should looks like this: `$state.go('app.login', { lang: 'en', redirect: 'settings'`). The first parameter should be for the `app` state and the second one for the `app.login` state. But I can't find a proper way to do this.

```
.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/{lang}', // Example url: /en
    params: {
            lang: null
    }
})
.state('app.login', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/login/{slug}', // Example url: /en/login/settings
    params: {
            redirect: null
    }
})
.state('login', {

    // When user enters '/login/settings', should be redirected to the 'app.login' state
    url: '/login/settings',
    controller: ['$state', function($state) {
            // So, I have to pass two parameters - 'lang' and 'redirect'
            // But first parameter is for to the 'app' state and the second to the 'app.login' state.
            // How can I pass a parameter at the same time for a parent and a child in one '$state.go'?
            $state.go('app.login', { lang: 'en', redirect: 'settings' })

            // Full link should looks like `/en/login/settings`
            // === `/{lang}/login/{slug}`
    }
})
```

Comment: Child states inherits from parents so `app.login` includes also param `lang`. You should also describe what it currently does..

Comment: You redirect to settings. I guess that settings has its own view and state. It means that you should write something like `$state.go('app.login.settings', { lang: 'en' })`

Comment: If you use `abstract: true` on settings, it is state without its own controller and view..so there is "nothing". Just look at documentation..

Comment: @bigless of course, my states have views, but I removed it for snipped needs to clarify the code. Sorry if it confused you.

Your answer did not solve the problem in 100%, but it gave me the impetus to try it again, so thanks :) So... the solution was very simple: I had to write `$state.go('app.login', { lang: 'en', slug: 'settings' })`. I had to change `redirect` to `slug` and all works.